# print console output in multiple sheets

Tags: java, selenium

I am using print stream to print my console output as a result. Below is my code:

```
  printstream myconsole=new printstream(new fileoutpoutstream(filelocation));
  system.setOut(myconsole)
  myconsole.print("module"+","+"status"+","+"result");
```

Now this will create a new file with a single sheet and print module, status and result as a column header and all of my console will follow these; example:
search clicked  pass  will be following module status and result respectively.

I completed these for one of my module with 20 outputs. Now I wanna try it for another module. So I want to print my console output in same file but in different sheet. How should I do that? Could you please help me?

Comment: Are you using CSV for this?

Comment: csv as well as xls too..Its working perfect for showing my automation test result in single sheet for both of these file....But I need to test module wise and for one module I have at least 20 conditions to be tested..So I want other module output in same file in different sheet.How should I do that?